# Setting element height using jQuery doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, height

I have a weird problem with a WordPress theme, I'm trying to set the height of a div using jQuery but also if the CSS return me the correct height that I've set the div keep his orginal height.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#featured-template section").each(function(){

        $( this ).height( 454 );
        alert($(this).height());//it's not 454!!! WHY?

    });
})(jQuery);
```

If you check it you can see that the CSS give me the height:454px but if you check the layout of the div it still have the original height.
Is my first time that I use a WP theme and this is so weird, why if the CSS give me the height that I've setted the div still not change his height? 
You can chek it here:
[website wordpress theme](http://roots.eco)

Comment: It works fine in isolation so your question doesn't contain enough information to help. (Isolated example: https://jsfiddle.net/4kspjL7c/1/)

Comment: you have an error in your js file

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).ready(...) is not a function`  - any reason you are creating a new, and not just using one of the ones that are already there?

Comment: first of all check jquery is not defined in your site... and above code is working if you include jquery library